# select the dataframe values with R

Tags: r

I have dataframe with customers names and the year of their arrive, i want to know if in the dataframe i have a same name on different years. For example 
Guillaume 2018
Guillaume 2019

here is the code that I tried in R (but I'm sure he work well) and example of my dataframe. 
Thanks in advance,

```
data %>%
group_by(nameclient, year) %>%
filter(year==2019 & year == 2020)

 nameclient             year
 PLEIN AIR VACANCES     2019
 BELLENGER Ronan        2020
 HOWARD Kimberley       2019
 HOWARD Kimberley       2020
 HUPPES Tamar           2019
 LEVIEILS Severine      2020
 HUPPES Tamar           2019
```

Comment: you can use table (df$nameclient) to get the answer

Comment: What should your desired output look like?

Comment: Not sure how you want the output to be. Maybe `data %>% group_by(nameclient) %>% filter(n() > 1)`

Comment: @AbdallahDIALLO I've edited your question with the output you requested in an answer below. Please add the desired output in your question and delete your answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your output should look like, but one possible solution is the following

```
data %>% 
  group_by(nameclient) %>% 
  summarise(n_different_years = n_distinct(year)) %>% 
  filter(n_different_years > 1)

# A tibble: 1 x 2
#   nameclient       n_different_years
#   <chr>                        <int>
# 1 HOWARD Kimberley                 2
```

or, if you want to see the exact years and not the number of different years in which a client arrives

```
data %>% 
  group_by(nameclient) %>% 
  filter(n_distinct(year) > 1)

# A tibble: 2 x 2
# Groups:   nameclient [1]
#   nameclient        year
#   <chr>            <int>
# 1 HOWARD Kimberley  2019
# 2 HOWARD Kimberley  2020
```

---

#### EDIT

After you specified what your output should look like, just add `select(nameclient)` at the end of one of the two above pipelines, and you'll get only the `nameclient` column.

Answer (score 0):

In base R, we can `split` `nameclient` based on `year` find the common ones using `intersect` and subset that from the dataframe.

```
subset(data, nameclient %in% Reduce(intersect, split(nameclient, year)))
```